# divide the even number in the list

Tags: haskell

I was trying to half the even numbers in the list

```
halfEvens :: [Int] -> [Int]
halfEvens xs = [x `div` 2 | x -> xs, even x]
```

the error is 
       **error: parse error on input ‘->’**

what does this mean and how to fix it? 
thanks

Comment: Aim your arrow the other way, so `<-`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the odd numbers in the list:

```
halfEvens :: [Int] -> [Int]
halfEvens = map (\x -> if (x `mod` 2) == 0 then x `div` 2 else x)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
halfEvens :: [Int] -> [Int]
halfEvens xs = [x `div` 2 | x <- xs, even x]
```

`x <- xs` is read as `x` *is drawn from* `xs`.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with your application of **->**, basically -> is an infix type operator also known as the function arrow(function builder), who's purpose is to apply the arguments on the left to the right so 
`from -> to` but list comprehension works with **<-** which takes an IO action and binds it to the left argument so `to <- from`, a small fix to your function:

```
halfEvens :: [Int] -> [Int]
halfEvens xs = [x `div` 2 | x <- xs, even x]
```

**[Edit: Ignore anything else from here]**
**=========================================================================**

But if what you're trying is to divide all even numbers by 2 then you are doing it wrong, as this function would return only even numbers, while discarding all others.

```
halfEvens :: [Int] -> [Int]
halfEvens [] = []
halfEvens (x:xs) = if even x then x `div` 2 : halfEvens else x : halfEvens
```

Would be the correct way to do  it, @AlexJ136 answer is also straight to the point, which seems much more efficient than mine, so I would go for it.